# How to apply searching facility to a listview in android

Tags: android, listview

I just want to know that how to add a search functionality to a listview in android here my listview is being loaded from the internet. Any help would be essential ,thank you

Comment: how about showing what you did first and then explaining what did not worked in it, instead of asking an end-to-end solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Please look at Psudo Code:---

public class SearchableAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

private List<String>originalData = null;
private List<String>filteredData = null;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private ItemFilter mFilter = new ItemFilter();

public SearchableAdapter(Context context, List<String> data) {
    this.filteredData = data ;
    this.originalData = data ;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

public int getCount() {
    return filteredData.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return filteredData.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // A ViewHolder keeps references to children views to avoid unnecessary calls
    // to findViewById() on each row.
    ViewHolder holder;

    // When convertView is not null, we can reuse it directly, there is no need
    // to reinflate it. We only inflate a new View when the convertView supplied
    // by ListView is null.
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

        // Creates a ViewHolder and store references to the two children views
        // we want to bind data to.
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_view);

        // Bind the data efficiently with the holder.

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        // Get the ViewHolder back to get fast access to the TextView
        // and the ImageView.
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    // If weren't re-ordering this you could rely on what you set last time
    holder.text.setText(filteredData.get(position));

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView text;
}

public Filter getFilter() {
    return mFilter;
}

private class ItemFilter extends Filter {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

        String filterString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

        final List<String> list = originalData;

        int count = list.size();
        final ArrayList<String> nlist = new ArrayList<String>(count);

        String filterableString ;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            filterableString = list.get(i);
            if (filterableString.toLowerCase().contains(filterString)) {
                nlist.add(filterableString);
            }
        }

        results.values = nlist;
        results.count = nlist.size();

        return results;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        filteredData = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

}

//in your Activity or Fragment where of Adapter is instantiated :

editTxt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    System.out.println("Text ["+s+"]");

    mSearchableAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());                           
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
        int after) {

}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
}
```

});

Comment: Thanks for the answer bro it will help me a lot