# search filter in android

Tags: android, search, filter

I've a code that can show the result of search menu in listview in dictionary application in android, the code can show the result which the same of the query that I typed in search. I need to show all the words which is containing the query not only the same word. here is my code:

```
public class ItemListBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
private Context contex;
private static List<Word> original_items = new ArrayList<>();
private static List<Word> filtered_items = new ArrayList<>();

private ItemFilter mFilter = new ItemFilter();
private LayoutInflater l_Inflater;

public ItemListBaseAdapter(Context context, List<Word> results) {
    this.contex=context;
    original_items = results;
    filtered_items = results;
    l_Inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

public Filter getFilter() {
    return mFilter;
}

public int getCount() {
    return filtered_items.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return filtered_items.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = l_Inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txt_word = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        holder.txt_result= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.txt_word.setText(filtered_items.get(position).getWord());
    holder.txt_result.setText(filtered_items.get(position).getResult());
    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView txt_word;
    TextView txt_result;
}


private class ItemFilter extends Filter {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        String query = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
        final List<Word> list = original_items;
        final List<Word> result_list = new ArrayList<>(list.size());

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            String str_word = list.get(i).getWord();
            String str_res = list.get(i).getResult();

            if (str_word.toLowerCase().contains(query) || str_res.toLowerCase().contains(query)) {
                result_list.add(list.get(i));
            }
        }

        results.values = result_list;
        results.count = result_list.size();

        return results;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        filtered_items = (List<Word>) results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: use adapter like this: `class MyAdapter extends MatchableArrayAdapter<Word>`, get it from [here](https://gist.github.com/pskink/2dd4d17a93caf02ff696533e82f952b0)

Comment: Please look at following my answer.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40573404/how-to-apply-searching-facility-to-a-listview-in-android/40573768#40573768